# How to run Python subprocess consistently and in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, popen

I wrote a python script that converts `mp3` to `wav` with `mpg123`. Then `ffmpeg` takes the output of `mpg123` and upsample it. Finally, `ffmpeg` output file uploads to cloud. All these steps must run consistently.

```
subprocess.run(['mpg123', ...])
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', ...])
upload()
```

Suppose, I have many `mp3` files and I'd like to run 10 threads at the same time. I know that Python offers threading in `subprocess.Popen`, `threading`, `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing` modules. What is the right way to parallelize this process?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MPipe](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe/) library:

```
from mpipe import OrderedStage, Pipeline

def increment(value):
    return value + 1

def double(value):
    return value * 2

stage1 = OrderedStage(increment, 3)
stage2 = OrderedStage(double, 3)
pipe = Pipeline(stage1.link(stage2))

for number in range(10):
    pipe.put(number)

pipe.put(None)

for result in pipe.results():
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to use standard python modules without a need to install other libraries.